# Disable track_vars from htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to disable php.ini directive `track_vars` from `.htaccess`. I use this command

```
php_flag track_vars 0
```

On the first line of my `.htaccess` file. I don't get any errors but when I open my index with this code inside

```
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

I get the `$_COOKIE` array. From the manual:

> track_vars boolean
>
> If enabled, then Environment, GET, POST, Cookie, and Server variables can be found in the global associative arrays $_ENV, $_GET,
>   $_POST, $_COOKIE, and $_SERVER.

So what I want to do is **NOT** populate those arrays automatically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the line below the one you quoted [on this manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.track-vars), you will see why this setting has no effect:

> Note that as of PHP 4.0.3, track_vars is always turned on.

PHP 4.0.3 was released in October 2000. This setting will probably be removed from the manual soon, as it hasn't been relevant to anybody for a very long time.

Comment: Really?! I missed that?! That's a new low for me! However as an alternative I found out that `variables_order` works for disabling these variables.

Comment: @php_nub_qq While confirming that `track_vars` is indeed dead, I came upon [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68008) reporting that setting `variables_order` to an empty string doesn't have the desired effect, but setting it to an invalid one does. I haven't verified that, though, or have any idea what versions are affected.

Comment: That's the conclusion I came to as well. Also setting it to a valid value like `S` for example would still disable all globals.